# Using Fontawesome 5.7 icons with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, font

I'd like to use this Fontawesome version with Openlayers 3. I tried changing the font value from FontAwesome to Font Awesome Free, but nothing happens. On the map appears a square (it means that the unicode cannot be found inside the font).

```
return new ol.style.Style({
  geometry: geom,
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '\uf041',
    font: '20px FontAwesome',
    // font: 'Font Awesome Free',
   })
});
```

Comment: Did this work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809479/use-semantic-ui-or-font-awesome-icons-as-markers-in-openlayers3/27932615#27932615 ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The strange thing is that it works great with Glyphicons. Instead, the FA icons are loaded throughout the application, except on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on something similar recently using FontAwesome Free.  Where you have the font property, try this (assuming that you are using the latest free FontAwesome) :

```
font: '900 20px "Font Awesome 5 Free" '
```

I went through a similar issue and one thing that I discovered is that for FontAwesome Free to work correctly the font weight should be 900.  This was during a proof of concept demo.

In the current production version using the pro version of FontAwesome, we need to wrap double quotes around the font type (ie; "Font Awesome 5 Free") and I assume it is the same with the free version too.  Out of curiosity, I just tested what happens when the double quotes are removed and I get the "square" on the map.

Hopefully, these items can help you.  Good luck!

Comment: It worked! Thank you Pkay!